# Not Showing Welcome Page JSP

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp, web-inf, welcome-file

I have created dynamic web project in eclipse and added index.jsp file, obviously thats my welcome page.I have added it in web.xml,I am using angular js for front-end interface management.

here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" metadata-complete="false" version="3.0">
<welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ValidateLogin</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ValidateLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ValidateLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ValidateLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ValidateLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

now what my issue is When I run the project it is showing loading and not opening any content. but if I added the project url+index.jsp in browser address bar then the page loads successfully. I am using route provider in angular js script and that is as follows

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'appController'
    ]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.jsp',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    }).
    when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/Home.jsp',
        controller: 'MainController'
    }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

}]);
```

here is my **dir structure**

[image]

what is the issue ? can anyone answer ?

Comment: Is that file name correct? Notice you didn't give `.jsp` extension in your web.xml, it should be `index.jsp`

Comment: have you tried with <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

Comment: @Sridhar I have tried all that method. but still same.

Comment: "but if I added the project url+index.jsp then the page loads successfully" where do u add it, plz elaborate

Comment: Where the `index.jsp` file exists, can you post the folder structure?

Comment: @maiklahoz that is I used , see my code above

Comment: @underdog in the browser address bar

Comment: @ShajeerAhmd in your code above you put <welcome-file>index</welcome-file> you need to add file extension .jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Add.jsp extension in index

Make sure your index.jsp is outside WEB-INF folder

For accessing the jsp the correct url will

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.jsp
```

Change the port no as per your server. You need to provide the project url for accessing the jsp. Say you have 4 projects deployed on your server each having index.jsp. How will the container figure out which index.jsp to run if you don't provide the project url.

Comment: you wrote in the question when you add the project url jsp loads fine.

Comment: Yes it is.. I have edited the web.xml as you mentioned.but its not loads the welcome page..

Comment: Re-read your question, what do you mean by jsp loads fine. And now you say does not load the welcome page

Comment: I can open the welcome page if i typed its absolute path like http://localhost:8080/Application/index.jsp .. But its not loading when i run the project or typed as localhost:8080/application/

Comment: This issue has happened with me; some solutions; clear server cache restart your server; delete web.xml put another one; create a new app & copy the code

Comment: Let me check that.. The server takes lot of times to reload the changes

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned welcome file without any file extension

```
     <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
```

just add valid welcome page with file extension, if may be your file is index.jsp

```
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

and your $routeProvider configuration doesn't affect your welcome page loading you mentioned in the web.xml. route provider only affect after your angular js loaded...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the welcome-file property is mentioned like this:
   index.jsp
2. Make sure the index.jsp is present parallel to WEB-INF.

Hope this works.